# selenium ide extract text from input tag [value attribute]

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am using selenium IDE for writing test case and I am trying to extract content in value attribute of below tag

```
<div id="inputcontainer_f-5" class="FGIC" style="max-width:none;"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="f-5" id="f-5" class="dummyclass FastEvtFieldFocus" value="TEXT_I_WANT_TO_GET" readonly="readonly" spellcheck="true" tabindex="-1" style="">
</div>
```

My selenium IDE code

```
comment    | Target                   | value
store text | xpath=//input[@id='f-3'] | EXTRATCED_CONTENT
echo       | ${EXTRATCED_CONTENT}
```

Result : I am getting empty string

echo : ""

If i try to change the xpath as  `xpath=//input[@id='f-3']/@value` I am getting following error

```
storeText on xpath=//input[@id='f-5']/@value with value EXTRATCED_CONTENT Failed:
The result of the xpath expression "//input[@id='f-5']/@value" is: [object Attr]. It should be an element.
```

How do i extract and store `TEXT_I_WANT_TO_GET` in variable `EXTRATCED_CONTENT` and echo it

Thanks
Jk

Answer (score 0):

Try this below.

```
//input[@id='f-3']@value
```